# Local Group Policy Powershell script to add MyGlue extension in chrome and edge

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo

**I installed the module PolicyFileEditor through the command "Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor"

Is there a way in which i can write a script using this module that would add MyGlue on Favorites Bar (with favorites bar being always shown) for Chrome and Edge**

I have done it through the LGPO but not through PowerShell script.

We cant do it manually as we are the MSP and we need to push this script through our RMM on all the workstations which we manage

Any help is appreciated

PS: This Needs to be a powershell script for LGPO as the workstations are not in domain but workgroup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
Write-host "Trusting PS Gallery"
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host "Installing PolicyFileEditor"
Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host "Installing MyGlue Chrome Extension Add-On (set LGPO)"
$MachineDir = "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol"
$RegPath = 'SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist'
$RegData = 'bfcdaalpeodhimbiipneeaoeogkkminc;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx'
$RegName = '1'
$RegType = 'ExpandString'
Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path $MachineDir -Key $RegPath -ValueName $RegName -Data $RegData -Type $RegType -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host  "Updating LGPO w/o restart"
echo N | gpupdate.exe /target:Computer /force
```

But please make sure that the value name '1' does not already exist for another add-on, otherwise it will be overwritten.

You could solve it e.g. like this:

```
$RegName = '1'
if ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:$RegPath").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $RegName) { $RegName = '2' }
if ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:$RegPath").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $RegName) { $RegName = '3' }
if ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:$RegPath").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $RegName) { $RegName = '4' }
```

But this is not nice, maybe there is a better solution: e.g. with RegEx or a loop, which checks the value names and takes the next free available number as name.

Somthing like: `$RegName = "Take the next available (not existing) number as name (string)"`